# Stop page from scolling up on link click

Tags: javascript, html

**Fixed! Solution found on the end of this question**

I've been working on a website where I have a Index page and a Info page. When you scroll down in the Index page and click the link to the Info page I want the Info page to open on the same position as the Index page was scrolled to.

I read about [ScrollSneak](http://queirozf.com/entries/javascript-example-preventing-page-scroll-hiccups-on-refresh-or-navigation-using-scrollsneak) and several similar questions and explanations here on Stackoverflow but could net get it to work for myself. I am quite a noob on javascript and am only beginning to learn how to use it. Can someone perhaps give me a example how to actually apply it to a link? I seem to fail to see what element actually links it to the actual link.

Code I found and applied below (gist link removed cause I have too low reputation to add more than 2 links xD check ScrollSneak for the file)

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--i'm using jquery too -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- include scroll_sneak.js -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/scroll_sneak.js"></script>

        <!-- now activate scroll sneak -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var sneaky = new ScrollSneak(location.hostname);

            // you want to prevent scrolling when form #my-form is submitted
            document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit = sneaky.sneak;

            // or maybe you want to prevent scrolling whenever any link within 
            // a list-option is clicked:
            $('li a').each(function(){
                // note the use of 'this' instead of '$(this)', because we
                // want the raw element, not the jQuery object       
                this.onclick = sneaky.sneak;
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="info.html"><img src="IMG/info_inactive.png" onmouseover="this.src='IMG/info_active.png'" onmouseout="this.src='IMG/info_inactive.png'" /></a>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Overlay code Im using right now

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
 var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
 document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
});
</script>
```

**SOLUTION!**

I was able to find a working code on [this forum topic](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?58146-Keeping-Scrollbar-Position-On-Refresh), the submitter found it on another topic on Stackoverflow. Without futher ado, the code!

*First you need a read-cookie function. Put this in the  section of your page:*

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
function readCookie(name){
return(document.cookie.match('(^|; )'+name+'=([^;]*)')||0)[2]
}
</script>
```

*Next you modify the body tag as follows:*

```
   <body onScroll="document.cookie='ypos=' + window.pageYOffset" onLoad="window.scrollTo(0,readCookie('ypos'))">
```

*NOTE! Tested in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. "Surprisingly" this does not work in IE, but who uses IE anyway? -_-*

**Thanks everyone for helping me out, it is much appreciated ;)**

Answer (score 1):

If Taffer's solution is not working for you, you can try adding the scroll position as a get param.

(Disclosure: I do not use jquery, I prefer Mootools, but this should work)

Add an identifying class to each link you would like to scroll on the new page:

```
<a class="linkandscroll" href="info.html">link</a>
```

Then on each page, add this:

```
<script>

    /* Method to return get params from url
    thanks to: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html
    */

    function getUrlParameter(sParam)
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Method to link and set scroll get param */

    function linkAndScroll(element){
        /* get link element's href attribute */
        var href = element.attr('href');
        /* get curent scroll position */
        var currentScroll = $('body').scrollTop();
        /* create new url */
        var url = href + '?scrollto=' + currentScroll;
        /* change page location */
        window.location.href = url;
    }

    /* on doc ready */

    $(document).ready(function(){

        /* loop through each scrolling link */

        $('a.linkandscroll').each(function(){ 
           /* add click event to call linkAndScroll method */
           $(this).on('click', function(){
                linkAndScroll($(this));
                return false;
            });
        });

        /* If scroll param is set on this page, do scroll now */

        var scroll = getUrlParameter('scrollto');
        if(scroll){
            window.scrollTo(0, scroll);
        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I applied the classes to all my links and added the script to every page. Sadly it still does not seem to work. I decided to take out the loading overlaying div, took out a small scroll bar in a div I had in the middle of the page and tried different browsers cause I thought this might confuse the script, yet it still keeps scrolling to the top.

Comment: Hmm... I will stop being lazy and whip up a test example this weekend. Stay tuned ;)

Comment: Thank you, that would be really great if you have the time for that. Would really appreciate it ^^

Comment: I fiddled around some more and searched the whole web it seems but still can't find a working solution :C 

I want to note that I'm using ucoz.com to upload the site. The homepage is from ucoz, on the back end I can edit this in their pages list and edit the css. The other pages I've uploaded to their server myself and are plain text files. I tried to link only the text files since I thought perhaps some (invisible) Ucoz code was interfering with the script, but still no success.

Comment: At last! I found a solution :D I will post it on the top!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll need scrollsneak, it's way more simple than that.
There are several solutions depending upon what you want, either JSRef:

```
<script>
function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollTo(500, 0);
}
</script>
```

(expanded upon here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp )

The space where it says 500 is to scroll on the X-axis(left and right), the 0 is for the Y-axis(up and down). You just change the numbers until you find the position you like.
And to make it go to another page and then execute this, you could make a script that takes some parameters like the URL of the link and specific position(or value of the element the link is contained within), and puts them into use, like so:

```
<script>
function linkAndScrollTo(theURL, xPos, yPos){
   window.location.href = theURL;
   window.scrollTo(xPos, yPos);
}
<script>
```

Or if you want it to scroll to a certain element in general, you can add an ID to the elements that ought to be "scrollable to", and then have the link lead to that ID on the next page. For example:

```
<div>
   <a href="http://www.yourPage.com/Info.html#theElementsIDHere">SomethingSomethingDarkside</a>
</div>
```

There are probably more, I hope this answered the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am trying this code now. As you said and it sais on the W3schools website, the 1st code should scroll automatically to the value (500) of the page when opened?

However this does not seem to work for as it is right now. Unless I misunderstood.

I am using a div (loading) overlay, since my site has a few heavy images I don't want people to see it load. Might that interfere with the scroll code? (code is added in the question above)

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, neither should Chrome. But I think in that case it might be best to make a script function in the first page to attach parameters to the URL, and one in the target page(info.html in this case) to retrieve the URL.

See Eclectic's solution, I think he's already provided the solution. :)

Comment: At last! I found a solution :D I will post it on the top!